# Windows Vista system writing files offline takes forever with emacs... why?

Tags: windows-vista, emacs, performance

Normally I run my Vista system connected by wireless to a network containing the domain to which it belongs.  When I code in emacs, it is zippy and fast.

When I take my laptop home, emacs freezes sometimes for 10-15 seconds.

I think what it is doing is writing a backup file for my text file.
To do that, I'm guessing file permissions have to be validated... by
the server that's no longer there.  And after some long, time,
Vista says OK anyway.

I use emacs on other machines.  Never had this problem.

Any suggestions as to what the real cause is? Cures?

Love my emacs, hate my vista.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to see where it's hanging.  In the `*scratch*` buffer, evaluate

```
(setq debug-on-quit t)
```

then during one of the hangs, type C-g.  You should get a backtrace that tells you what it's doing.

Comment: Nice idea. I'll try it.